# Data insertion problem in sqlite

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

I am inserted first record in sqlite, and when i am trying to add another it shows "Database Locked" error.
the code is:

```
- (void) addRecord:(NSMutableDictionary *)recordDict
{

    if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "insert into Product(ProID, BarCode , ProductName ) Values(?,?,?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    NSInteger recordId = [[recordDict objectForKey:@"ProID"] intValue];
    NSLog(@"%d",recordId);
    sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 1,recordId);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [[recordDict objectForKey:@"BarCode"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [[recordDict objectForKey:@"ProductName"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else
    {//SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
        rowID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
        NSLog(@"last inserted rowId = %d",rowID);

             //Reset the add statement.
             sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you format your code please?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your code jumps out at me.  If you are getting "Database Locked" then that means you have an open transaction that is locking the database.  This could be in your app (in another thread perhaps) or in another app that is also accessing the same database.

Answer (score 0):

"Database Locked" means the database is not writable, two reasons for this -

1) You forget to finlalize your previous compiled statement or forgot to close the database try this in your previous query -

```
sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
sqlite3_close(database);
```

2) Are you copying the database in Documents directory before using it? You can't modify the database in bundle itself. Here is the code to copy the database in documents directory.

```
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase{
    // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
    BOOL success;

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
    if(success) return;

    // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];

    [fileManager release];
}
```

Here is how to get database path -

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName] retain];
    NSLog(@"%@",databasePath);
```